# Trigger Azure Web Jobs through Webhook url

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an issue in triggering Azure webjobs using Webhook url.

I created a simple 'NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute' Azure web job below is the code

For example:

```
 class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main()
    {
        var test = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsDashboard"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration(test);

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("ProcessMethod"));
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

Below is the Function class code:

```
 public class Functions
{
    // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
    // on an Azure Queue called queue.

    [NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
    public static void ProcessMethod(TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine("This is First call from Main Method.");
    }
}
```

Now when i tried to call the webjob using the webhook url :

https://sample.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/SampleWebJob2/run

Its giving this response:

"No route registered for '/api/triggeredwebjobs/SampleWebJob2/run'"

There is no details captured in AzureWebJobsDashboard

Let me know if its the correct way to call the Azure webjobs on demand. Is there any setting that im missing here.

Please guide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are indeed some points to note：

1. When you deploy your WebJob, make sure your WebJob run mode is Run on Demand.

[image]

2. Delete `RunAndBlock()` in the main method or it will run without stop, it's for continuous WebJob.
3. When you request the WEBHOOK make sure set the right authorization, you could get the webhook and the name, password in the WebJob properties page. Here is the Postman page.

[image]

[image]

Then you will be able to run the webjob from WEBHOOK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this really helps. I have one more query. I just wanted to run the same Azure web job with different set of  parameters at different schedule. Please let me know the changes i need to do for that.

Comment: @user1941025,about how to pass parameters you could add ?arguments={your arguments} to the end of the url. The REST API is described here:https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job

Comment: @user1941025, if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: There is no longer the option to deploy as "Run on Demand" - only "Triggered" and "Scheduled". Any idea how to solve the problem with `No route registered for....`?